# Worklight Mobile Simulator file not found error

Tags: dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm using Worklight 6.1 Studio on a OS-X Mavericks, and get the following error while launching the Mobile Browser Simulator. This appears in the Liberty Server console, and the simulator never loads in the browser.

```
[WARNING ] SRVE0190E: File not found: /dojo/dojo/_base/kernel.js
```

Any ideas on why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please edit the question and explain how exactly you are loading the MBS.

The MBS is part of Worklight Console (and available only in the Worklight Studio Eclipse plug-in).
The proper way to interact with it, is like so:

1. Create an app, add an environment, etc...
2. Right-click on the application folder > Run As > Run on Worklight Development Server
3. Right-click on the project folder > Open Worklight Console
4. Click on the preview app of the environment

Then, the MBS will load and preview your app within it.

Comment: Thanks. It turned out that I Wasn't running the server first. Duh!